# How to open new TabbedPage from ContentPage?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to open (using any method) the TabbedPage from ContentPage.

My main App code:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        MainPage = new ConnectPage ();
    }
}
```

My ConnectPage uses XAML, code:

.cs file:

```
public partial class ConnectPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ConnectPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        void connectDevice(object sender, EventArgs args){
            connect_btn.Text = "Connecting...";
            connect_btn.IsEnabled = false;
            var mainapp_page = new MainApp ();
            Navigation.PushAsync (mainapp_page);
        }
    }
```

XAML file:

```
<Button x:Name="connect_btn" Text="Connect Now" Clicked="connectDevice"></Button>
```

Above method throws error:

> PushAsync is not supported globally on iOS, please use a
>   NavigationPage

My MainApp.cs (which contain tabs):

```
public class MainApp : ContentPage
{
    public MainApp ()
    {
        var tabs = new TabbedPage ();
        tabs.Children.Add (new Tab1Page{Title="Tab1" });
        tabs.Children.Add (new Tab2Page{Title="Tab2" });
        tabs.Children.Add (new Tab3Page{Title="Tab3" });
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried googling that exact error message for examples on how to fix it.. since you are utilizing the `PushAsync` method.. one would almost automatically think that you would need to implement the `await` method call.. but It's a guess for me at this point..

Answer (score 1):

You can either update your'r app's `MainPage` property and set that to the page you want to display, use stack navigation or present a page modally.

Setting a new main page will provide no way for the user to go back:

`App.Current.MainPage = new SomeOtherPage ();`

If you want to use stack navigation, you will have to wrap your initial page into a `NavigationPage`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.MainPage = new NavigationPage (new FirstPage ());
    }
}
```

Than you can use `Navigation.PushAsync()`.

If you want to present a page modally, so it is shown on top of your current page and can be dismissed, use:

```
Navgiation.PushModalAsync(new Page());
```

However, this will still require to wrap your current page into a `NavigationPage`.

There are other ways too, like `CarouselPage` or `MasterDetailPage`. I recommend you look at the [documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/pages/) for all of your options.

Comment: I dont want to use navigation for the MainApp (TabbedPage). I just want to show it over the ConnectPage. Is that possible?